# Constructor.newInstance() without knowing parameter sequence?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, javassist

Take this code for example :

```
public class User {
  private String username;
  private String password;

  protected User()
  {}

  public User(String username , String password)
  {...}

  //getters & setters
}
```

We can use `User.class.getConstructors()` and find there are 2 constructors  , and with `constructor.getParameterTypes()` , we can identify there's one constructor with two String parameters.
We can also use reflection to find two properties : username and password.
But , **at run time** ,  we don't know the proper sequence of the two parameters being used to call constructor.newInstance(?,?).

`constructor.newInstance(username , password)` , and `constructor.newInstance(password , username)` are both legal but with totally different result.

I cannot use `User.class.newInstance()` and set property value because the no-arg constructor is protected.

I encounter this problem because I am trying to write a generic JPA CRUD tool. List/Read/Update/Delete are OK. But now I face the problem that I cannot online create an object. The entity classes are all with a protected no-arg constructor (so I cannot use class.newInstance()) , and one a-lot-of-parameter public constructor (but the parameter names are erased at runtime).

How to do this ? Does javassist or other proxy-techniques help ? how ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Constructor<?> c = class.getDeclaredConstructor();
c.setAccessible(true);
c.newInstance();
```

That's what JPA will do anyway, because it instantiates objects via their no-arg constructor.

Comment: Wow , thanks for telling me that I can modify protected to public . I didn't know JVM allows this before.

Comment: I wouldn't modify a class for the purpose of instanciating it, as the consequences of that modification are not easy to foresee. That's called a "Hack" :)

Comment: it is not modifying it. It just just making it accessible temporarily

Answer (score 1):

That might be just a workaround, but couldn't you create the User using (I omit reflection for the purpose of readability)

```
User u = new User(null, null);
```

and then set the properties in your tool?

```
u.setUsername(...);
u.setPassword(...);
```

You could generate code that is more or less atomic, so it wouldn't matter to you

Answer (score 0):

The order will be the same at runtime though, so why not just figure out the correct order, and treat it as such.